# Requiring a Password / Passphrase to view contents of category with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, categories, password-protection

I'm trying to set something up where when a user clicks on a category link within the navbar, it asks them for a password / passphrase to view that categories posts. I've done a lot of digging, and I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I figured I would be able to solve this with a little bit of script work, but I can't even find something to get me started. Help?

Comment: Well I'm assuming you want to do this server side? I would write some php script that checks the user input against some value stored in my database and then have the user submit a form the checks their value against the value in the database(either using ajax or a new http request).

Comment: I'd prefer to do it server side. I found a plugin that I thought would work for this (http://themehybrid.com/plugins/members), however, even when viewing the awesomely detailed documentation for it, I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something that would require a plugin. In this case I would write something along the lines of this.

This script is assuming the user is making a http POST request to this page, probably by submitting a form somewhere on your website.

If any of this looks foreign to you feel free to ask and I'll be happy to clarify :)

```
<?php
//Create new database connection
$idForPassword = 5;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "DBusername", "DBpassword", "DBName");

//Create new prepared statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM sometable WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idForPassword);

// execute query
$stmt->execute();

// bind result variables
$stmt->bind_result($result);

$stmt->fetch();

// Hash the password so we aren't storing a password as plain text in the database
// ideally you also add a salt to your password but since this is just an example
// I'll leave that part out
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if($password == $result)
{
    //allow user access
}
else
{
    //deny user access
}
```

edit: A little more info on [Salting and Hasing passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). I'd recommend reading it whenever you get the chance since its a fairly easy way to implement basic level of security if you plan on storing passwords in a database.

> The security issue with simple hashing (md5 et al) isn't really the
>   speed, so much as the fact that it's idempotent; two different people
>   with the same password will have the same hash, and so if one person's
>   hash is brute-forced, the other one will as well.  This facilitates
>   rainbow attacks.  Simply slowing the hash down isn't a very useful
>   tactic for improving security.  It doesn't matter how slow and
>   cumbersome your hash algorithm is - as soon as someone has a weak
>   password that's in a dictionary, EVERYONE with that weak password is
>   vulnerable.
>
> Also, hash algorithms such as md5 are for the purpose of generating a
>   digest and checking if two things are probably the same as each other;
>   they are not intended to be impossible to generate a collision for. 
>   Even if an underlying password itself requires a lot of brute forcing
>   to determine, that doesn't mean it will be impossible to find some
>   other bit pattern that generates the same hash in a trivial amount of
>   time.
>
> As such: please, please, PLEASE only use salted hashes for password
>   storage.  There is no reason to implement your own salted hash
>   mechanism, either, as crypt() already does an excellent job of this.

Comment: After some fiddling, this worked for me. Thanks for giving me an easy to understand start point. =)

Comment: @ignu5_ glad to hear it! I also went back and elaborated a little about hashing and salting passwords.